# How to get a character index in a string

Tags: java, string

I want to get a character index in a `java.lang.String`. So, for example, I want to find the `'2'` character index in the `"0123456789"` string (the index will be 2). There is any method in the String class to use for this, or a simple code?

Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Please be more **specific**. The letter `a` in what `String`? What have you tried?

Comment: Ok, @ElliottFrisch I edit the answer.

Comment: It's still not clear. You can just use `charAt`, but... what problem are you actually trying to solve? Getting the first `a`? Getting *any* `a`? Getting the second character? Etc.

Comment: `s.charAt(1)` will return `'a'`, which is one way to "get it", but that's ludicrous, as in what's the point of getting it? Did you mean "how to *find*"? If you did, then `s.indexOf('a')` is the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate through the String and look for a character you seek.

Just use a for loop like this:

```
String test = "I want to test something";
for(int i=0;i<test.length;i++) {
  char t = test.charAt(i);
  // do something with char
}
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt%28int%29

Comment: `indexOf()` would be easier.

Comment: @Andreas your solution finds only one character of a. I applied a general approach if someone wants to do more then just compare. Of course you can go with `indexOf`, but the downside is to only get one value. In case you have several 'a' characters, then you would have to iterate through and add `indexOf('a', startIndex)` each time you want to look further.

Comment: True, and question is weakly written, but it does say "get *a* character", implying that only one character is needed. Of course, it should have said "*find* a character", so maybe it's meant to really say "find *all* instances of a certain character", in which case your answer would be perfect.

Answer (score 2):

`index` will be -1 if 'a' is not in this string.

Note this code will only find the first 'a' in this string. If you need to find multiple locations of a character, then loop through the string using solution in another answer.

```
String str = "there is a letter";

int index = str.indexOf('a');
```

Comment: Thanks, i've solved it!